# How can I prevent tables from being effected when sorting source data?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a table with 10 columns for project management. Each row represents a task to be completed. I would like to summarize this information on a dashboard (same workbook, different sheet). The summary will show the 'Next 5 Tasks' (including overdue tasks) that are NOT marked complete (Cell values with 'No' in column 9 of the source table). The only three columns I want to show are End Date, Project, and Task (8, 1, 2), in this order. The rows should be ordered by the SOONEST end date first, then the next, etc. If the tasks are overdue, they should appear first, with the oldest due date appearing first.

However, if I change the way the source table is sorted, the newly created 'summary table' as I am calling it, is also sorted. I do not want this to happen.

The columns in my original table (Table 1133) are (in this order):
Project | Task | Category | Priority | Owner | Effort | Start Date | End Date | Complete? | Notes

In my summary table, I am using these formulas to pull in the information I want:

Column 1 - Due Date:
    `=INDEX('Master Task List'!B6:L31,MATCH("No",Table1133[Complete?],0),8)`

Column 2 - Project:
    `=INDEX('Master Task List'!B6:L31,MATCH("No",Table1133[Complete?],0),1)`

Column 3 - Task:
    `=INDEX('Master Task List'!B6:L31,MATCH("No",Table1133[Complete?],0),2)`

The output is this:

Due Date | Project | Task
12/12 | Marketing | Design the brochure
12/13 | Administrative | Complete expenses for Q1
12/15 | Secret Project | Secure meeting location
12/15 | Travel Overhaul | Write RFP for local agencies
12/31 | Branding Campaign | Send email to media contacts

I would like the data to stay this way, no matter how the original table gets sorted. However, the dates in this newly created table are rearranged in my if the sorting in the source table changes.

Is there a way to prevent my summary table from being effected by sorting the original data? Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you include the code that is causing you problems, we might be able to help you fix it.  Without your code, we would have to start from scratch, which would make the question "too broad" and it will get closed very quickly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply - I have updated my original question.

Comment: I don't know if that is enough to help. You've given formula with no example data, no example output, and read your question text: how likely do you think it is that *anyone*, anywhere knows what you mean by: *Summary table in excel - show specific columns, sorted by date, conditional on column data, and limited to 5 results - VBA, Formula, or other?* (and further, how well does that question title actually describe, concisely, your specific problem, which seems to be the sorting of the data?  hint: it doesn't).

Comment: Updated the question. Hopefully there is enough information now.

Comment: Hi. Is the Power query addin by MS out of question?

Comment: It is not - I am installing it now, though I have never used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [Power Query addin by MS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605) to achieve desired result, and it's fairly easy.

Let consider such raw data (the source table, yours has 10 columns, mine 5 but the idea is the same).
[image]

Now we use the power query. Put cursor into the table and choose Create query from table.

In Excel 2016 you get this (with just maybe 2 steps in the "APPLIED STEPS" pane on bottom right. Additional steps will appear as soon as you apply filter and sort and other steps.):
[image]

Now you need to "teach" the query what to do each time it gets refreshed.
I chose these steps:

1. Filter the Completed tasks, so only FALSE remained.
   [image]
2. Sorted the Due Date from A-Z. You should do this EXPLICITLY, even if the source data is already sorted in the right order. Remember, we are teaching the query, what to do each time it gets refreshed.
   [image]
3. Removed unnecessary columns (Complete, Lead). Note, the filter still applies, even if you remove them from query.
   [image]
4. Find "Keep rows" and set it to 5 max.
   [image]

The result looks like this:
[image]

Comment: This looks great - one question I do have, though, is do I have to manually refresh the query every time a change is made to the source data?

Comment: That is correct. The result will update only on refresh.

Comment: I was able to get it to auto-refresh every 1 minute by going to 'Data, Connections' and changing the properties. This works for my purposes. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to be of help. Yes, right! I forgot that you can do that. I see you are a fast learner, well done.